There holds strong maximum principle for p-caloric functions?
That is, there holds  strong maximum principle for solutions of $u_t- \Delta_p u=0$? I know that it holds for caloric functions, that is, for solutions of $u_t- \Delta u=0$

Sorry, but the question is not clear to me... Also, what is $\Delta_p$ (is it the $p$-Laplacian?)? What kind of solution do you mean? Are there initial/boundary conditions?

Yes, it is the p-Laplacian. Any answer about kind of solution would be good. For instance weak energy solutions.

Can you please add all the details to the question? Including boundary conditions/intial conditions....
